# Combine Varible Tuples

Tags: python, dataframe, tuples

I have a tuple with variable length:

```
[72, 252], [259.1, 293.8, 79.1, 113.8], [316.2, 316.2, 136.2]
```

What can I do to compute difference between values like:

For the second set:

```
259.1 - 293.8, 259.1 - 79.1, 259.1 - 113.8, 293.8 - 259.1, ...
```

For the third set:

```
316.2 - 316.2, 316.2 - 136.2, ...
```

Comment: Do you want the subtraction of all possible pairs combinations in a given tuple?

Comment: 1) Those are lists, not tuples 2) Are you trying to subtract all values from the first value, or all values from all other values? 3) What have you tried so far? Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Those list are separated by `,`, so they must be inside something...maybe it's a `tuple` of variable length `lists`

Comment: If the question has been answered, can you select an accepted answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my suggestion:

```
lists_of_variable_length = [[72, 252], [259.1, 293.8, 79.1, 113.8], [316.2, 316.2, 136.2]]

def get_differences(list_):
    '''Returns differences between non-identical elements in list_'''
    len_ = len(list_)
    return [list_[lv1] - list_[lv2 ] 
            for lv1 in range(len_)    # iterate twice over the list
            for lv2 in range(len_)    # to account for all possible pairs
            if not lv1 == lv2]        # but don't select identical elements

# use map to apply that function to all lists 
result = map(get_differences, lists_of_variable_length)
```

Edit:

To get the individual values, you would do:

```
result[0][0] # get first difference from first list
result[0][1] # get second difference from first list
result[1][0] # get first difference from second list
```

Comment: That's it!! Thank you so much.

Comment: How do you access all elements after get_differences?

Comment: Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. =((

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the value of i[0]-i[1], i[0]-i[2], etc., you might try something like this:

```
output = []
mylist = [[72, 252], [259.1, 293.8, 79.1, 113.8], [316.2, 316.2, 136.2]]
for group in mylist:
    diffs = []
    for item in group[1:]:
        diffs.append(group[0]-item)
    output.append(diffs)
```

You could also do all this with list comprehensions if you feel comfortable with that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what is your wish, but how about this?

```
import itertools

example = [[72, 252], [259.1, 293.8, 79.1, 113.8], [316.2, 316.2, 136.2]]

def f(x):
    out = []
    for xi in x:
        outi = []
        for i in itertools.permutations(xi, 2):
            outi.append(i[0] - i[1])
        out.append(outi)
    return(out)
```

Comment: Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.   =((